# I coded a program which finds out class attendance percentage but the output is always zero

Tags: c++

This is the code. I am a newbie so please help.
I don't know why it's  output is always zero.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Prgram Coded To Find Attendance Percentage*/

int main()
{
   int class_held, class_attended;

   cout << "How Many Classes Were Held?" << endl;

   cin >> class_held;

   cout << "How Many Classes Did You Attend?" << endl;

   cin >> class_attended;

   int class_attended_percentage = (class_attended / class_held) * 100;

   cout << "Your Attendence Is " << class_attended_percentage << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Integer division will do that to you.

Answer (score 3):

Two integers divided will always result in an int, in your case in `0` and `0 * 100 = 0`

You need to cast at least one of the integers into double or float before dividing (I casted both):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Prgram Coded To Find Attendance Percentage*/

int main()
{
   int class_held, class_attended;

   cout << "How Many Classes Were Held?" << endl;

   cin >> class_held;

   cout << "How Many Classes Did You Attend?" << endl;

   cin >> class_attended;

   int class_attended_percentage = (static_cast<double>(class_attended) / static_cast<double>(class_held)) * 100;

   cout << "Your Attendence Is " << class_attended_percentage << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to cast _at least one_ integer to a `double` (or a `float`) before dividing. The compiler will then automatically _promote_ the type of the other, before doing the division.

Comment: @TimRandall oh yes you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Dividing 2 integers always gives the answer in an integer, where the decimal part is truncated. Since `class_held >= class_attended`, your answer will be 0.

Cast one of the values, `class_held` or `class_attended`, as a `double`. Here's the code which will work correctly:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*Prgram Coded To Find Attendance Percentage*/

int main()
{
   int class_held, class_attended;

   cout << "How Many Classes Were Held?" << endl;

   cin >> class_held;

   cout << "How Many Classes Did You Attend?" << endl;

   cin >> class_attended;

   int class_attended_percentage = (class_attended / (double)class_held) * 100;

   cout << "Your Attendence Is " << class_attended_percentage << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `class_attended` and `class_held` are `int` types.

When you use an integer to operate with another one, the result will be floored. As you calculate the percentage, the result is definitely a floating-point number less than 1, which is floored to zero eventually.

To get a correct result.

1. Define your variables as floating-point types:

```
float class_held, class_attended;
```

2. Or cast to floating-point before your operations:

```
int class_attended_percentage = ((float)class_attended / (float)class_held) * 100;
```